# UI-Router $state.includes() not returning true for child states

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have the following states (small snippet of all states):

```
   .state('reports', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/reports',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })

    .state('reports.program', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/program',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })

    .state('reports.form', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '/form',
        template: '<ui-view/>'
    })

    .state('reports.program.overview',{
        url: '/overview?start&end',
        data: {...},
        breadcrumb: {...},
        params: {...},             
        templateUrl: 'app/reports/program/overview.html',
        controller: 'reportingProgramOverviewController',
        controllerAs: 'vm',
        resolve: {...}  
    })
```

When I am at `reports.program.overview`, and use `$state.includes('reports');`, it return false. The same goes for `'reports.*'`.

It is my understanding that `$state.includes()` will match child states as well? So If I am under `state1.state2.state3` it will match any of those three individually of I check for them via that method.

How can I see if I am currently under the `reports` state?

Answer (score 0):

This is not supported: check [244](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/244) alebo [1229](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/issues/1229)

Based on comments, you can do something like this:

```
$state.matches = function(stateName) {
    var regexp = new RegExp('^'+stateName.replace(".", "\.").replace('*', '[\w]+'))
    return regexp.test($state.current.name);
}
```